# Accidentally commented out main drive in /etc/fstab, cant boot, any way to fix this without clean install?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

Yall are gunna chuckle at this one, but in an attempt to resolve a slow boot issue, I opened up etc/fstab, commented what I thought was an unused drive causing the issue, and then rebooted to see if it resolved the issue.

In retrospect, I think I just commented out the main drive because now I can't boot. No backups either.

Is there any way I can fix this? Is there any way to open up the filesystem of my now defunct OS and edit that etc file when I can't even boot?

Answer (score 1):

2 methods:

- from a live session. Use the usb/dvd you used to create the system and boot from that. This is the easiest method; if you do not have a live session create it using another machine if possible.
- from grub rescue. Press a key during boot and grub will show its menu and from here you can get a root prompt.

Both methods let you use "root" to edit files on your disks.

In case you do not know how you messed it up or do not know how to fix it; if you remove `/etc/fstab` it will be recreated on boot.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the instructions and was able to get it. I wasn't able to pull up the grub menu, but I loaded the iso of Ubuntu desktop to a USB using Rufus, selected 'try ubuntu' on boot, then found the drives to the defunct OS under `media/ubuntu/<partition ID>/etc/fstab`. They also showed up as SSD's on the taskbar.